# Interactive GUI-like command line merging tool (like BeyondCompare or WinMerge) for Linux

Tags: linux, unix, merge, diff, command-line-interface

May be something that uses reverse-video to show the differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would go for [vimdiff](http://www.debianadmin.com/vimdiff-edit-two-or-three-versions-of-a-file-with-vim-and-show-differences.html). See this [tutorial](http://amjith.blogspot.com/2008/08/quick-and-dirty-vimdiff-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 2):

[`sdiff(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sdiff)

Comment: Useful, but cannot compare two directories.

Answer (score 0):

I use the **Midnight Commander**

It can compare folders and files (check the Command menu, `F9` via keyboard)

When comparing files, use `Enter` to navigate to the next diff, `F5` to merge the selected diff from the right to the left.

Unhappily it does not support modifying the files while merging, and it also does not support merging to the right.

To install it on Linux:

```
sudo apt install mc
```

On Mac:

```
brew install mc
```